# How to check string against whitelisted characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, ecmascript-6

I have a bit of code that transforms user input to ensure the only allowed characters are abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789

https://jsfiddle.net/py4pnr0L/

```
value = 'GHJHlk;sxa787BVK'
value = value.toLowerCase()
value = value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-]/gi, '-')
console.log(value)
```

Returns: ghjhlk-sxa787bvk

How would I go about not transforming, but just testing to find if a given string contains characters outside the permitted range?

All I want to know is true/false for a given input string.

I am using ES2015 so if the cleanest solution is available using ES2015 then that is fine.

Comment: You mean `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(value)` ?

Comment: Is the set of allowed characters the same? You can just use your own negated character class with `.test()` if yes. `/[^a-z0-9-]/i.test(value)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why does your answer and anubhava's vary in regards to i.test(value) versus .test(value).  What does the "i" do?

Comment: Erm, it is your regex :) `/i` is  a case sensitivity modifier, `/[a-z]/i` = `/[a-zA-Z]/`. Also, my regex includes a hyphen, anubhava's does not. Is that the code you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

you can use match method , try something like:

```js
value = 'GHJHlksxa787BVK';
 
console.log(!value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method:

> Executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns `true` or `false`.

No `/g` modifier should be used with this method so that the `lastIndex` property could not mess the results. See [*Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results) for details.

Your regex `/[^a-z0-9-]/i` (matches any character that is not in the `a-z` and `A-Z` and `0-9` ranges and not `-`) can be used here. Just take out the `/g`.

```js
var value = "GHJHlksxa787BVK";
document.body.innerHTML = /[^a-z0-9-]/i.test(value);
```

The `/i` is a case insensitive modifier, `/[a-z]/i` = `/[A-Za-z]/`.

Comment: A subtlety to the question / my code is that the whitelist does *not* permit upper case characters.  Which I guess means taking out the trailing "i" from your regex?

Comment: Now, `/[^a-z0-9-]/i` checks if a string contains chars other than `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `-`. If you want to trigger `true` when `A-Z` is present, remove the `/i` modifier.